# Wordpress won't update edits

Tags: php, wordpress

Problem is - I'm logged in as admin, working on a website, let's say I have doctors on my website, and they are in categories. I deleted one doctor, cause he left work in that clinic. I deleted his page, where was info. I go to visit website, everything seems good doctor gone. Than my friend says why you didn't delete that doctor, I said I deleted and checked. So the thing is than I logged in as admin I can see my edits, then I log out I see doctor that doesn't even exist(i deleted it even from trash.) HOW TO FIX THIS?

UPDATE: Ok, i figure it out, that problem is only with doctors page, let's say contact page is updating normal...

**SOLUTION**: My URL was broken, I don't know why and how, but I created new page, reupload info, and it worked.

Comment: Is there a serverside cache that needs clearing?

Comment: clear the cache ,in your server and tell your friend to clear his browser cache

Comment: We cleared browser cache, but i didn't try server cache, i will now

Comment: There are two possibilities, one you need to clear your site cache, if you are using any. And another ask your friend to clear his/her browser cache and check it again.

Comment: Well, i tried clear cache of server and of browsers in my pc and friends. still nothing... Trying to view in incognito but still nothing

Comment: Can plugin cause this problem?

Comment: Are you using Cloudflare? Is it maybe a menu item still?

Comment: No, I'm not using Cloudflare.

Comment: do you use wpcache plugin or something? not the browser cache.

Comment: @TahaPaksu No, I did once, but it kind a crashed my slider revolution so i deleted it, I did a week ago my website optimization, deleted couple plugins which I don't use, can this be a problem that I deleted something I shouldn't?

Comment: Can you reinstall the plugin and clear cache from that plugin? Maybe it has something to do before plugin uninstalls?

Comment: In fact I don't remember which plugins was it :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually deleted the page, and not just left it in 'Bin' or 'Trash'?

If you're logged in as Admin, I believe deleted, and draft pages still show as normal so you can preview them.

Try logging out of /wp-admin/ and see if you can still access the page. If it says 'Page not found', then your page is still in Wordpress and hasn't been deleted.

Comment: I deleted it from bin/trash. I try to access page throw incognito, and I CAN.

Comment: @Rokas, Can you share the page link so that we can check as a guest user whether it is accessible or not at our end.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)